# Reset dynamic Min Width in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabric js vs 1.7,as per my application I need to reset dynamicMinWidth using condition. when I am writing in side the text box then dynamicMinWidth increase but I want to reset the value of dynamic min width when I am writing in next line in fabric text box.

```
console.log(e.target.dynamicMinWidth);
```

Comment: `reset the value of dynamicMinWidth` what do you mean by this? you want to reset the width of textbox?

Comment: yes,I want to set the width of text box dynamically

Comment: obj.set({height:60}) it is working but width is not working